# A faster way to find out if any word in a list is a substring in a longer word

Tags: python, bash, algorithm, perl, go

What I have

- A string `s` of length `m` (where m > 3)
- A huge list `L` of `words` (length > 2)

What I want to know

- Is any `word` in `L` a substring of `s`

Currently i have `L` split up into files, one file each for each word-length *16.txt*, *15.txt* ... *04.txt*
I then iterate over these files from *n.txt --> 04.txt* and basically do

```
cat n.txt | while read w; do if [[ $s =~ $w ]] ; then echo $w; fi; done
```

It's painfully slow **there has** to be a better way to do this.

Additional info:

- `L` contains about 200k words and is fairly static so I don't mind a complicated time consuming setup if it means greater speed
- There are several different such lists `L` but only one of them needs to be searched at a time.

I'm pretty language agnostic (se tags) but pseudo code is also fine

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `grep` without splitting the list:

```
grep -oFf list.txt <<< "$s"
```

- `-o` will only output the matching substrings
- `-F` will interpret the lines in list.txt as fixed strings, not regular expressions
- `-f` will tell grep what file to use as the source of the patterns to match
- `<<<` in bash takes the following word and makes it input to the preceding command